# Getting all objects from all IEnumerables within all IEnumerables

Tags: c#, linq

Within a project of one of our clients I often need to get *all* children of all items in an `IEnumerable`.

This is a simplified version of the models:

```
public class Parent
{
    public IEnumerable<Child> Children {get;set;}
}

public class Child
{
}
```

When I now want *all* children of all `Parent` instances in a `List{T}` I now use a regular `foreach`, like so:

```
List<Parent> parents = GetAllParents();
var children = new List<Child>();
foreach(var parent in parents)
{
    children.AddRange(parent.Children);
}
```

I was wondering if this could be done in one Linq statement?

Something like:

```
var children = parents.Select(....
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to project parents sequence into lists of children and flatten those lists into single sequence:

```
var children = parents.SelectMany(p => p.Children);
```

Query syntax looks like

```
var children = from p in parents
               from c in p.Children
               select c;
```